# Ant: SCP:No response from server

Tags: ant, ssh, exec, scp, openssh

I'm trying to send some files to a remote machine using `Ant <scp>` but getting ***no response from server error.***

Tried with verbose option and got following response.

```
  [scp] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  [scp] Next authentication method: publickey
  [scp] Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
  [scp] Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
  [scp] Authentications that can continue: password
  [scp] Next authentication method: password
  [scp] Authentication succeeded (password).
  [scp] Disconnecting from xx-hostname-xx port 22
  [scp] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to socket closed
```

code has no issues since it's working fine with other host machines. Issue must be somewhere else. Have anyone came across this issue before? Thanks in advance.

P.S: I can connect to the remote machine from my local using `putty` without any issues. I have installed `openssh` on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `scp` program installed on the remote system? The local scp instance (or `ant` in this case, I suppose) needs to run another copy of scp on the remote system. If the local program failed to run `scp` on the remote system, you'd get this behavior.

Edit:

Your local `scp` client (ant in this case) is going to make an ssh connection to the remote host. Through that connection it's going to try to run a program named "scp" on the remote system. The two scp instances will communicate to do the file transfer. So the program on the remote system has to be named "scp", and it has to be in the command path of the ssh session. I don't think WinSCP fulfills either of these criteria. It doesn't install a program named "scp" or "scp.exe". And at least on my PC, it didn't install itself into my command path.

The simple test would be to make an interactive ssh connection to the remote system and see if you can run "scp" within that session. If you get an error, then `ant` is also going to get an error.

Comment: I have already installed Winscp on the remote machine(Win 2012). Still no difference in error

Comment: You are right. "scp" command doesnt work on my remote machine but worked on other machine (where file transfer is successful). So how do i install scp on win2012?

Comment: I don't have experience with OpenSSH for windows, but I'd expect that whoever made your OpenSSH package would also make a version of scp available, either as part of the same package or in a different package.   

If you're using Cygwin, it looks like [OpenSSH](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fopenssh%2Fopenssh-6.6.1p1-3) comes with a copy of the scp program. So it could be that the program is on the host, but it's not being found because of the command PATH or some other reason. Or the OpenSSH install could be missing some files.